# nginx - serve page depending on ip

Tags: nginx, static, request, ip

I want to serve a special page to people coming from certain ip (an ip of a building complex i know before hand), and to all other ips server my normal page.

I searched the stack but found are answers about redirect rules.
I don't want to redirect but just answer the same request with two different ways that depend on the ip.

Can I do it with nginx or do I have to pass the request on to my server side code and handle it there?

--- EDIT ---
The actual flow to make this more clear:

- incoming request to www.mysite.com ->
- check ip of request ->

  - if ip is from an ip i know beforehand ->
    (even better if I can check range of ips or array/file with ips)

    - Serve inip.html <- special page
  - otherwise ->

    - serve index.html <- normal page

so www.mysite.com can respond with 2 diff pages depending on the request ip (and not by redirecting to mysite.com/something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally rewrite the path:

```
location <whatever> {
    if ( $remote_addr == <ip> ) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /other-path/$1 break;
    }
    # ... normal config here
}
```

[Source](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if)

To your edit:

This works just like any rewrite (`mod_rewirte` in Apache), so the user won't get any redirect statuses. It will be transparent to the user. In other words: you are serving the page based on the user ip.

If you want to specify more complex rules for the ip's you can match them with regex `~*` instead of checking equality `==`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was away for the weekend. i'm not sure how exactly this works under the hood. Does it rewrite the uri to /other-path, then processed again by nginx (without returning a redirect to the user), and then a location rule for /other-path catches this?  or is other-path already the page to be served?  can you check my edit and show me how the rule fits my flow? I'd understand better how to use it then. TY

Comment: Thanks again. your explanation and the reference to apache mod_rewrite really helped. I advise anyone who bumps into this and needs some extra info to head over to the apacie mod_rewrite documentation.  
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html  
really helped me understand how it works.

Comment: Yw. For future you might want to ask these kind of questions on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) instead here.